# Salesforce Public Repository

Tags: lightning-web-components, files, static-resources

I want to create an Email Signature Banner in Salesforce. Once copied, we will paste it in Gmail signature.

Is there a way to upload an asset image that will be still visible outside the Org?

I've tried static resource and files but it is not working.

Currently, I 've been uploading those pictures on HubSpot and copy their URLs into my LWC.

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario needs a public URL for web/email use, Documents can be displayed publicly.

- Switch to Salesforce Classic > All Tabs > Documents
- Choose [X] Externally Available Image
- Upload your PNG file and click Save

Select the preview and copy the image. The underlying image URL will look like this and works in a GMail signature: https://streams.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01567000009POxH&oid=00Db0000000e729&lastMod=1704196361000

[image: Salesforce Document - Externally Available Image]